# Decrease upgrade time when changing application parameters for a Service Fabric Application

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a multi-tenant scenario (each tenant has its own Service Fabric Application instance) were the tenant can activate/deactivate individual Service Fabric Services (we expose the services as an extension concept to the tenant in the UI).

*Example: Tenant#1 activates the Email extension which will activate the Email Service Fabric service.*

**Requirements:**

1. When the tenant activates an extension they should be able to provide configuration (example: smtpserver)
2. The tenant should be able to activate extension rapidly (there are ~20 different extensions)
3. The extension should be and running in seconds

**Current Implementation**

The activation of an extension is handled in the following way (using the email example above):

1. The tenant activates the email extension through the UI and provide the address to the smtpserver
2. The email service is created in the tenant´s application
3. An upgrade of the application is triggered adding the provided smtpserver configuration to the application parameter list
4. Service Fabric starts a rolling upgrade
5. Time flies (minutes in our case)
6. The application is upgraded and the email service is up and running

The scenario above work, the service starts and can read the smtpserver configuration. However the experience for the tenant is not optimal.

**Problem**

During the upgrade no other service can be activated since configuration cannot be changed during an ongoing upgrade in Service Fabric.

The tenant therefore has to wait until the application is upgraded (takes minutes) before they can activate/deactive extensions again. If the tenant want to activate 10 extensions they will have to wait a long time.

I have tried the following to decrease the upgrade time:

1. Set the HealthCheckStableDurationInMilliseconds to 0
2. Set the HealthCheckWaitDurationInMilliseconds to 0

The upgrade process still takes too long (around one minute).

**Question**

Since we only want to change the Service Fabric Application Parameters are there any other way to speed up the upgrade process or work around it completely?

Note: Because of technical limitations we cannot batch extension activations. Each extension has to be activated one at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to dynamically create and delete the services on activation and de-activation, have you considered passing the needed configuration as the initialization data arguments to the service creation?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.description.servicedescription#System_Fabric_Description_ServiceDescription_InitializationData

Please note that you cannot change the initialization data once the service is created.

Comment: Good suggestion and thanks for taking your time! However, since the user needs to be able to reconfigure the service (extension) this does not work for us in this case. One of the main problems is that the whole application gets in a "upgrade state" when changing the configuration. Do you know if there is anyway to only trigger an upgrade for a single service instead of the whole application to (perhaps) speed things up?